# How to show Relative Layout if it's not empty

Tags: android

I have a `Relative Layout` and the visisbility is set to gone if the `Recycler View` is empty. My problem is that it doesn't return when I add things into the `recycler view`

This is my Class

```
  @Override
  public View inOnCreateView(View root, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstancesState) {

    View view = mRoot;

    addButton = view.findViewById(R.id.addItemsButton);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent addButton = new Intent(getActivity(), AddItemsActivity1.class);
            startActivity(addButton);
        }
    });

    mModelList = new ArrayList<>();


    mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view1);
    mAdapter1 = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mModelList);
    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);

    editText = view.findViewById(R.id.editTxt);
    btn = view.findViewById(R.id.btn1234);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mModelList.add(new Model(editText.getText().toString()));
            mAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter1);

relativeLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.Dairy_RelativeLayout);
        if(mAdapter1.getItemCount() == 0){
            relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


    return root;
}
```

I also know it's not my adapters fault because when I set it to View.Invisible I can see that the view gets bigger when items are in it, since its set to wrap content.

Comment: Please post your full file. It is not really possible to debug what you're attempting without seeing the full flow.

Comment: Looks like something is still missing - I don't see any reference to a RelativeLayout?

Comment: I fixed it. please check it out

Comment: Iv'e added it now

Comment: Do you ever set it back to `View.VISIBLE`? I don't see that anywhere in the posted code. You would need do the item count check any time there are changes to your adapter list, and set to `GONE` if there are zero items, and `VISIBLE` if the count is > 0.

Comment: check item count on button click as well where you are adding/removing new items and change visibility according to that

Comment: @RachitSolanki Thank you I've got it now